# How to solve repeating call the same Android Activity

Tags: android

Activity 1:
A `ListView` that show list of friends.
After `onClick()` of an item in the friend list, it will go to Activity 2 which is `ProfileActivity` showing the details of such friend.

Activity 2 (`ProfileActivity`):
And there is a `Button`, after `onClick()`, will go to Activity 3 (`NearByActivity`) which shows list of twenty nearby friends within 10km.

Activity 3 (`NearByActivity`):
After `onClick()` of an item, it will go to Activity 2 (`ProfileActivity`).

The story is that from Activity 2 to Activity3, I don't want to `finish()` Activity 2 before start Activity because user may want to go back.

So, the question is:
How to finish the Activity2 if user click any item in Activity 3 so that preventing Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3...

Although Activity 2 will call many times, the profile details is depending on which user is clicked.

Or any other suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

You can override onActivityResult() in Activity2. When you finish Activity3 just pass result to Activity2 .

for Example

```
    //In Activity2
onActivityResult(ReqCode , ResultCode, Intent) {
  if(ResultCode == FINISH){
     finish();
  } else if(ResulCode == DO_SOMETHING_ELSE){
     // Do Somthing
  }

}

//Activity 3
onClick1(){
 setResult(FINISH);
 finish();
}

onClick2(){
  setResult(DO_SOMETHING_ELSE);
  finish();
}
```

See onActivityResult [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Answer (score 0):

when a button click from activity 3. just send a broadcast message (you can also use localbroadcas). and in activity 2 there will be a broadcastreceiver so if it get broadcast message containing exit command then it will finish()